# How to solve "Symbol lookup error" by using JPL on Ubuntu11.04?

Tags: java, shared-libraries, swi-prolog, ubuntu-11.04, jpl

I'm coding a program in Java and I would like to connect to Prolog. Thus, I decided to use JPL. It is perfectly to use JPL on Windows Vista. Later, I have to change the OS platform to be Ubuntu 11.04. Unfortunately, there is an error:

> symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/i386/libjpl.so: undefined symbol: PL_is_initialised

**Environment:**

1. Ubuntu 11.04
2. Java version 1.6.0_24
3. Eclipse Galileo  Version: 3.5.2
4. SWI-Prolog version 5.10.1 for i386
5. Jpl (apt-get install swi-prolog-java)
6. Family.java + family.pl

I explain steps of working and problems as follows.
 step1: Install swi-prolog + jpl using Synaptic Package Manager 
[image: Swi-prolog Installation]

step2: Run Family.java , found an **error** 
[image: JPL not found Error]

step3: Configure the library path at **VMarguments** 
[image: Set VMarguments]
step4: Run again, there is an error 
**/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/i386/libjpl.so: undefined symbol: PL_is_initialised**
step5: I also config the environment but the error still the same. 
[image: set environment arguments]

The method that I used to solve the problem as in step 3 and 5 I searched from the internet. I can not find other solutions to try. Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently this bug has been reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/swi-prolog/+bug/597619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for every supports. Now,i can manage this problem. I found a suggestion from page **http://code.google.com/p/javanaproche/wiki/HowToJPL**

Following the instructions, i change the swi-prolog version to be a building form source pl-5.10.1. Finally, it works. I think the problem happens because the swi-prolog getting from synaptic manager doesn't set to be a shared library. If anyone knows how to set a share library , it might be work.

Comment: Good answer, it worked on one 32-bit machine I tried, but I'm getting an error on 64bit. Any ideas why? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336371/compiling-prolog-jpl-on-ubuntu-11-10-64-bit

Answer (score 1):

You have to config the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, I think. Try to add the location of the so-library file. And make sure, your `System.loadLibrary();` call is relative.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done according to your suggestions but it doesn't work.  the java library path =/usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/i386/ but there is an error "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libjpl.so in java.library.path" even if there is a libjpl.so at "/usr/lib/swi-prolog/lib/i386/libjpl.so"